# Need help converting opencv in c# to vb.net

Tags: c#, vb.net, opencv, porting

So I am having what appears to be meltdown trying to figure out this code and get it ported over to a vb.net equivalent. Quite frankly I don't want the code letter for letter, I just want to do the same process to an image in vb.net. The issue being that everywhere I have looked, the recommendation is to use a wrapper and not OpenCV directly. The wrapper is emgucv.net

At any rate, I will show the code.

```
static void Decaptcha(string filePath)
{
    // load the file
    using (var src = new Mat(filePath))
    {
        using (var binaryMask = new Mat())
        {
            // lines color is different than text
            var linesColor = Scalar.FromRgb(0x70, 0x70, 0x70);

            // build a mask of lines
            Cv2.InRange(src, linesColor, linesColor, binaryMask);
            using (var masked = new Mat())
            {
                // build the corresponding image
                // dilate lines a bit because aliasing may have filtered borders too much during masking
                src.CopyTo(masked, binaryMask);
                int linesDilate = 3;
                using (var element = Cv2.GetStructuringElement(MorphShapes.Ellipse, new Size(linesDilate, linesDilate)))
                {
                    Cv2.Dilate(masked, masked, element);
                }

                // convert mask to grayscale
                Cv2.CvtColor(masked, masked, ColorConversionCodes.BGR2GRAY);
                using (var dst = src.EmptyClone())
                {
                    // repaint big lines
                    Cv2.Inpaint(src, masked, dst, 3, InpaintMethod.NS);

                    // destroy small lines
                    linesDilate = 2;
                    using (var element = Cv2.GetStructuringElement(MorphShapes.Ellipse, new Size(linesDilate, linesDilate)))
                    {
                        Cv2.Dilate(dst, dst, element);
                    }

                    Cv2.GaussianBlur(dst, dst, new Size(5, 5), 0);
                    using (var dst2 = dst.BilateralFilter(5, 75, 75))
                    {
                        // basically make it B&W
                        Cv2.CvtColor(dst2, dst2, ColorConversionCodes.BGR2GRAY);
                        Cv2.Threshold(dst2, dst2, 255, 255, ThresholdTypes.Otsu);

                        // save the file
                        dst2.SaveImage(Path.Combine(
                            Path.GetDirectoryName(filePath),
                            Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(filePath) + "_dst" + Path.GetExtension(filePath)));
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This should get you started:

Start here:

https://www.codeproject.com/Questions/405164/Use-OpenCV-in-web-application

```
Private Shared Sub Decaptcha(ByVal filePath As String)
    Using src = New Mat(filePath)
        Using binaryMask = New Mat()
            Dim linesColor = Scalar.FromRgb(112, 112, 112)
            Cv2.InRange(src, linesColor, linesColor, binaryMask)
            Using masked = New Mat()
                src.CopyTo(masked, binaryMask)
                Dim linesDilate As Integer = 3
                Using element = Cv2.GetStructuringElement(MorphShapes.Ellipse, New Size(linesDilate, linesDilate))
                    Cv2.Dilate(masked, masked, element)
                End Using

                Cv2.CvtColor(masked, masked, ColorConversionCodes.BGR2GRAY)
                Using dst = src.EmptyClone()
                    Cv2.Inpaint(src, masked, dst, 3, InpaintMethod.NS)
                    linesDilate = 2
                    Using element = Cv2.GetStructuringElement(MorphShapes.Ellipse, New Size(linesDilate, linesDilate))
                        Cv2.Dilate(dst, dst, element)
                    End Using

                    Cv2.GaussianBlur(dst, dst, New Size(5, 5), 0)
                    Using dst2 = dst.BilateralFilter(5, 75, 75)
                        Cv2.CvtColor(dst2, dst2, ColorConversionCodes.BGR2GRAY)
                        Cv2.Threshold(dst2, dst2, 255, 255, ThresholdTypes.Otsu)
                        dst2.SaveImage(Path.Combine(Path.GetDirectoryName(filePath), Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(filePath) & "_dst" + Path.GetExtension(filePath)))
                    End Using
                End Using
            End Using
        End Using
    End Using
End Sub
```

Comment: Unless im missing something, nothing in that code seems to work. It's just riddled with refs to things that dont exist and the ones that do work differently etc etc..

Comment: The "missing" stuff is the references to the OpenCV DLL's, I assume you have them.